# Как работает sep в print()

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())
print ("The next number for the number " ,a, " is " ,a+1,".", sep='')
print ("The previous number for the number " ,a, " is " ,a-1,".", sep='')
```

Вj фрагменте мы просто выводим следующее и предыдущее числа для данного числа. В данном случае sep используется для того, чтобы избежать пробела между a+1 и "." Немного непонятен механизм работы.

Comment: Непонятно, что именно непонятно. В самом вопросе дан ответ.

Comment: @Эникейщик, видимо, просто неочевидно, что sep - это сокращение от separator. Без этого действительно может быть не понятно, что это за аргумент, и почему в него нужно передать пустую строку, чтобы убрать пробел ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sep` задаёт разделитель, который будет вставлен между выводимыми значениями.

Когда вы не указываете `sep`, он по умолчанию считается одним пробелом. Поэтому если вы не хотите, чтобы вставлялся дефолтный пробел, вы указываете в качестве `sep` пустую строку.

На самом деле, гораздо более удобным способом формирования строки вывода c подстановкой в неё значений, считается вот такой:

```
print ("The next number for the number %s is %s." % (a, a+1))
```

или такой:

```
print ("The next number for the number {} is {}.".format(a, a+1))
```

А в самых последних версиях третьего питона появился синтаксис f-строк, который ещё удобнее:

```
print (f"The next number for the number {a} is {a+1}.")
```